# Accessing Python functions with Ajax

Tags: python, ajax, function, web

I’m new to python and web related code so excuse the probably dumb question. I was wondering if it’s possible for me to write some functions in python, and then for them to be used on a website.

Specifically, I have coded a few simple functions that take a users input (string of a musical chord like “Amin7sus2”) and return the notes that make up that chord (A, B, E, G). Now the goal is to have a web app where someone can type the chord, and then it accesses the python functions to return the notes.

I have a friend who does front end, and he mentioned Ajax to me for accessing python through jquery, but I can’t find any examples of it doing something quite like this.

It takes around 10 smaller functions to achieve the conversion from string to a list of notes, as well as accessing several dictionaries within python. I’m essentially looking for a way to feed the input from the web (a simple string) through my series of functions in python to finally return the list of notes.

Below is a very symbolic version of my python code that I wish to feed user input from the web into:

```
def dict1():
    #dict1
    return dict1

def func1(input):
    #input_to_chord_quality
    return input_to_chord_quality

def func2(input_to_chord_quality):
    #access dict1
    #quality_to_notes
    return quality_to_notes

def main():
    return func2(func1(input))
```

Can anyone offer some guidance on how to use python logic for a web app feature?

Answer (score 0):

You should read up about Web frameworks in Python - my personal recommendation would be [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/) but there are many. Look for one that is specifically suitable for writing Web APIs (REST or otherwise) - think of a Web API as a method of exposing server-side Python code through a Web (HTTP, or Ajax) interface.

Once you have started experimenting with building a Web API using a Python Web framework, and have specific questions, I suggest you come to StakcOverflow again and ask.

Good luck!

Comment: This might be a good point to get started: https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/creating-apis-with-python-and-flask (just a quick Google search will show many alternative posts, videos, books etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by learning a python backend like flask or django. But there is also something called [brython](https://brython.info/), which gives you the possibility to execute python code on the frontend.
My recommendation would be to try [this tutorial](https://brython.info/static_tutorial/en/index.html?lang=en) and writing something like this:

```
<script type="text/python">
    from browser import document

    def function(): 
        ...
        return "Test"

    document <= function()
</script>
```